# How can I find the permissions for sub-folders in file's path in C under Linux?

Tags: c, linux, path, stat

I'm trying to find all subfolders in a file's path that have 'others exec' permission.

I've tried to use `strtok(path_str,"/")` to break the path string, but when using `stat()` for the sub-directories of the root of the process I run, I get the "not a file or folder" error.

Any suggestions on how I can overcome this error?

Comment: Just log the pathnames you are feeding to `stat()`. I bet there is a mistake in your string-splitting algorithm. By the way, check out the `dirname()` function.

Comment: Can we see the smallest working code that reproduces your symptoms, and learn the actual `errno` you encounter?  A quick reading suggests that you are naively stat()ing the individual component names of your path, that is, tokenising "path/to/something" and stat()ing "path" (ok), "to" (ENOENT, probably), and "something" (ENOENT, probably).  Without code, however, it's all guesswork.

Comment: pilcrow, you are correct.
This is my problem, if I stat() the "to" from the directory i executed the process then it is not found which resulting in an error.

So, how else i can encounter this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it,

First I removed the first '/' from the path (I'm not fully understand why it so)
Than I Changed the code into do-while to access the file at the end.
So here is the entire code:

```
do{
    int retval;
    if (temp_ptr != NULL) //before the first strrchr its null
        *temp_ptr = 0;
    if (*temp_path)
       retval = stat(temp_path, statbuf);
    else
        retval = stat("/", statbuf);
    if (retval < 0){
        perror("stat");
    }
     printf("%s\n",temp_path);

    if(S_ISDIR(statbuf->st_mode)){
        printf("\tis a directory\n");
    }else if(S_ISREG(statbuf->st_mode)){
        printf("\tis a regular file\n");
    }


}   while ((temp_ptr = strrchr(temp_path, '/')));
```

Thank You caf and all for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If the path is `"long/path/to/the/file.txt"`, then you will need to call `stat()` on `"long"`, `"long/path"`, `"long/path/to"` and `"long/path/to/the"`.  If you don't care in what order you check these, the easiest way is probably to repeatedly use `strrchr()`:

```
char *s;

while (s = strrchr(path, '/'))
{
    *s = 0;
    if (strlen(path) > 0)
        stat(path, &statbuf);
    else
        stat("/", &statbuf);

    /* Do something with statbuf */
}
```

(The special-casing is for paths beginning with `/`, to check the root directory itself).

Comment: @caf: Shame on you for writing `if (strlen(path)>0)`! `if (*path)` is a lot simpler and avoids a whole unnecessary traversal of the string.

Comment: @R.: True, but my version of gcc performs that transformation itself, even on `-O0`.

Comment: Nice. Although I'm a bit surprised it does it on `-O0`. That could be disturbing to a lot of newbies when the function call disappears entirely while debugging...

Comment: @R.: It is a little surprising.  `-fno-builtin` does disable it.

Comment: @caf: Thank You,
I tried it and it gives me the following output:

/filepath/layer2/example.txt
stat: No such file or directory
/filepath/layer2
stat: No such file or directory
/filepath
 is a directory

So, it gives just the directory which is in the directory of my process.

Comment: @SnapDragon: That likely means that you don't have execute permission on `/filepath`, so you can't examine anything below it.

Comment: @caf: running stat() from Terminal works fine, and shows that all directories have exec permission for others.